# Conflicting swipe event with Webview and html5 page in android

Tags: android, html, webview, swipe, epub

Here i have issue with swipe event conflict with html5 page image gallery and webview swipe event in android.
I create an EBookReader app to read .epub files for android. My app have feature of swiping page. I have one .epub file with images, videos and image gallery, image gallery have 5 images on html page and at a time see 1 image, to see another image html page have scrollable image gallery, html page uses iScroll.js and panelnav.js for image gallery.

My ePub file has 10 html pages and my reader page support swipe scroll on page.

I implemented for navigation page using Custom Horizontal Scroller. i display html5 pages on webview and scroll one after another webview on Horizontal scroller pager. my web page swipe perfectly but when html5 page have image gallery with swipe feature, images are swipe but my webview is also swipe. i want to stop my webview swipe when my html page have image gallery with swipe in android.

Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.